# Running a j2ee web application as a website or under personal domain

Tags: web-applications, deployment, amazon-ec2, dns, web

Suppose I have a domain "www.mynewdomain.com", a Amazon EC2 instance "ec2-999-89-928-892.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com" and a j2ee web application "myapp.war".

Now I need to deploy my webapp in Tomcat/MySQL server in the amazon cloud and run the app as "www.mynewdomain.com". I know to deploy the application locally. I just want to know how to run my webapp without any port or context. How can I achieve this?

In short, my running webapp "http://ec2-999-89-928-892.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/myapp" should run as "www.mynewdomain.com".

Will be pleased to appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. **To change the path from `/myapp` to `/`** - set the `<context-root>` in your [`application.xml` file](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html) to `/`:

   ```
   <module>
       <ejb>myapp.jar</ejb>
   </module>
   <module>
       <web>
           <web-uri>web-client.war</web-uri>
           <context-root>/</context-root>
       </web>
   </module>
   ```
2. **To change your port from 8080 to 80** - If you work on ubuntu you can use [iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/)

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
   ```

   This will route all traffic coming from port 8080 to port 80
3. **To change your DNS from `ec2-999-89-928-892.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com` to `www.mynewdomain.com`** - You need to add a `CNAME` to your `DNS` tables pointing from `ec2-999-89-928-892.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com` to `www.mynewdomain.com`. If you use `AWS`'s `Route53` to manage your domain, you can find instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/R53Console.html), if not, look it up in your domain management help files.